# Copy and Rename at the same time - No such file or directory

Tags: cp

```
shuf -zn1 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 cp -vt /home/myspace/
result i.e. Image00005.jpg
```

BUT, I want to rename the file at the same time 
i.e. Image00005.jpg to Image.jpg

Tried:

```
shuf -zn1 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 cp -vt /home/myspace/image.jpg
cp: failed to access '/home/twitter/image.jpg': No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: `/home/myspace`? `/home/twitter`? O.o Also: `-t` always expects a directory.

Comment: cp: failed to access '/home/myspace/image.jpg': No such file or directory

Comment: Are you trying to copy one random file to a fixed name or did I miss something?

Comment: Correct - random to fixed name

Answer (score 2):

Since the `-t` form of `cp` only accepts a target *directory*, you will need to use the traditional `SOURCE` `TARGET` form e.g.

```
shuf -zn1 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 -I{} cp -v {} /home/myspace/image.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting --- shuf -zn1 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 
Image00002.jpg

shuf -zn1 -e *.jpg | xargs -0 -I{} cp -v /home/myspace/image.jpg
cp: missing destination file operand after '/home/myspace/image.jpg'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.

Comment: Did you remember to include the `{}` in the `cp` command?